# How did French “cacher” divide into English “cache” and “cachet”?

Tags: etymology

I encountered Merriam-Webster's [article on **cache** vs **cachet**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/blog/cache-and-cachet-whats-the-difference.htm) (while researching another word).
I understand it and [other websites that broach the confusion caused by these two nouns](http://grammarist.com/usage/cache-cachet/),
but none explain the process behind the dichotomy: How did the French verb « cacher » bifurcate into these two different nouns with different meanings?

Footnote: The French verb « cacher » (in modern 2015 French) appears to match the definitions of only **cache**. [Etymonline on **cachet**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cachet&allowed_in_frame=0)  cites the Old French dialectal *cacher*. Does this help?

Comment: If *cachet* means a seal on an official document I would imagine that the seal is ***hiding*** what's inside from public view.

Comment: I'm familiar with _cachet_ in two pronunciations: (a) /'kætʃət/ meaning social _mana_ or rank (which I would mark as UK speech), and (b) /kə'ʃe/ or /kæʃe/, which means either the same thing as (a), or a small aromatic bag of persistent herbs like lavender, carried on a lady's person or in her purse or trunk to provide pleasant odors for refreshment. The pseudo-french name for the lavender bag is, I think, typical of Victorian delicacy, like _commode_ or _toilet_; any subject in bad odor got a French euphemism, to prevent lowerclass laughter.

Comment: These are two ***different*** French words, which come from two ***different*** meanings of the French verb *cacher*. In French, *une cache* is a hiding place, while *un cachet* is a seal of the kind you press into hot wax. They both come from the old French verb *escachier* which meant something like *to press together*, which is what you do both when hiding something in a small place, and putting a wax seal on an envelope.

Comment: Or maybe *cacher* (to hide) comes from *escachier* from the idea of putting something under something else ... since *escachier* also could mean something like "to crush beneath a heavy object" (and is the derivation of the English word *squash*).

Answer (score 2):

Your own [source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cachet) gives a pretty complete answer:

> cachet (n.)
>   1630s, Scottish borrowing of French cachet "seal affixed to a letter or document" (16c.), from Old French dialectal cacher "to press, crowd," from Latin coactare "constrain" (see cache). Meaning evolving through "(letter under) personal stamp (of the king)" to "prestige." Compare French lettre de cachet "letter under seal of the king."

This indicates that there was an Old French dialectical meaning of *cacher* as "to press", which evolved into the Modern French word *cachet*, meaning "a seal affixed to a letter", which was then borrowed in 16th century Scottish with the same meaning.

The [entry on cache](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cache):

> cache (n.)
>   1797, "hiding place," from French Canadian trappers' slang, "hiding place for stores" (1660s), a back-formation from French cacher "to hide, conceal" (13c., Old French cachier), from Vulgar Latin *coacticare "store up, collect, compress," frequentative of Latin coactare "constrain," from coactus, past participle of cogere "to collect" (see cogent). Sense extended by 1830s to "anything stored in a hiding place."

Shows the English *cache* originating from a French-Canadian back-formation from the French verb *cacher* to the noun *cache*, meaning "a hiding place for stores".